# populating text from array with ajax

Tags: c#, ajax

There is a function in the controller that returns arraylist in json format with 3 values when I press the button.As you can see following log, this part works correctly.

[image: array]

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="Sira" name="Sira">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="Sehpa" name="Sehpa">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="Kat" name="Kat">
 <input type="button" id="btnGet" value="Bobin Konum Al" style="margin-top:40px;" onclick="GetKonum()" />
```

When the button is pressed into the above input texts, I want to populate the values ​​in the array in order.

```
function GetKonum() {
            $.ajax({
                method: "GET",
                url: '@Url.Action("BobinLevel3KonumAl", "Home")',
                datatype: 'JSON',
                success: function (result) {
                    console.log(result);
                    var konum;
                    for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                        konum = result[i];
                    }
                    document.getElementsByName('Sira') = konum[0].pop();
                    document.getElementsByName('Sehpa') = konum[1].pop();
                    document.getElementsByName('Kat') = konum[2].pop();
                  
                },
                error: function (xhr) {
                    alert("error: " + xhr);
                }

            });
        }
```

I get an error in the for loop, how can I populate the values ​​in json format into the inputs respectively?

Comment: Your first line in the for loop has a stray .va after the right paren.

Comment: I didn't have this in my code,I edit thanks but the error continues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just assign the values directly from the array:

```
success: function (result) {
    console.log(result);
    document.getElementsByName('Sira')[0].value = result[0];
    document.getElementsByName('Sehpa')[0].value = result[1];
    document.getElementsByName('Kat')[0].value = result[2];  
},
```

---

To further explain - in `result` you are receiving array of elements. You can just access them as array by index `result[0]` to get first result, `result[1]` to get second etc.. You should use some validation if array is not empty, or you get exception.

In regards to assignment to the textbox input, you need to find the respective input field. You do that by using `document.getElementsByName('Sira')`, but it returns all fields in an array. So you need to assign it to the first elements that was found:

```
document.getElementsByName('Sira')          // array of all elements
document.getElementsByName('Sira')[0]       // first input in the array
document.getElementsByName('Sira')[0].value // value of first input in array

document.getElementsByName('Sira')[0].value = "abc"; //this assigns the value
```

Comment: Thank you ! It worked when I use values ​​first input directly   in array.